# how Weka calculates Sigmoid function c#

Tags: c#, neural-network, weka

I am using weka with my dataset to train a neural network and now I want to use the results (weights and thresholds produced by weka) in my application and implement only the forward pass.

now the problem is that I don't know how exactly weka calculates the sigmoid function, with what conditions etc. In order to use the results produced by weka I really need this information and write the exact same code that is used  by weka.

can someone please tell me this? or provide me with a source that explains this thing? I would really appreciate the help.

I hope the question is clear and I need the answer Ungently

Comment: It might be a bit of a hunt, but you could check the source code: https://weka.wikispaces.com/Subversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source:

```
if (value < -45) {
  value = 0;
}
else if (value > 45) {
  value = 1;
}
else {
  value = 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-value));
}  
return value;
```

Pretty [simple sigmoid](https://svn.cms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/trunk/weka/src/main/java/weka/classifiers/functions/neural/SigmoidUnit.java) with a clamp using the logistic function.

That said, you're very likely not going to be able to replicate the results exactly with just that - there a great many details involved and you'll have to read [the source](https://svn.cms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/trunk/weka/src/main/java/weka/classifiers/functions/MultilayerPerceptron.java) and understand them all.

Comment: Thank You, I was already using this same code but the thing I needed was the source, thank You for providing me with that